# System of first order linear coupled PDEs

Tags: linear-pde

I'm in trouble finding the solution of this system of 2 PDEs:
\begin{equation}
\frac{\partial u_1}{\partial t} + a_1 \frac{\partial u_1}{\partial x} = b (u_1-u_2)\\
\frac{\partial u_2}{\partial t} + a_2 \frac{\partial u_2}{\partial x} = -b (u_1-u_2)
\end{equation}

with:
\begin{equation}
u_1 = u_1(t,x)\\
u_2 = u_2(t,x)\\
a_1,a_2,b = constant
\end{equation}

initial condition is given for t=0:
with:
\begin{equation}
u_1(0,x) = f(x)\\
u_2(0,x) = g(x)\\
\end{equation}

I'm really frustrated cause I'm not able to find any valid method to approach it. Is it possible to find an analytical solution to obtain explicit functions u1, u2?

Comment: I'm trying to follow your suggestion. So, the transformed PDEs system is:

\begin{equation}

sU_1(x,s)-u_1(0,x)+a_1\frac{dU_1}{dx}(x,s)=b(U_1(x,s)-U_2(x,s)) \\
sU_2(x,s)-u_2(0,x)+a_2\frac{dU_2}{dx}(x,s)=-b(U_1(x,s)-U_2(x,s))

\end{equation}

This should be an ODE system in $U_1(x)$, $U_2(x)$ with $s$ as parameter. Is it correct?
I will try to write the solution.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try a Laplace transform in $t$, obtaining a parametrized system of linear constant-coefficient ODE's in $x$.